# Why List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String>() this give TypeMismatch error

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, java-6

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String>()
```

When I use the above line compiler gives me type mismatch error. But as I understand Object is super class of String and if I create list of object then it should also accept String. So why above statement is wrong. I am looking for an explanation.

Comment: No. The type in generic doesn't work that way. You can do it with `List<? extends Object> list = new ArrayList<String>();`, but it is not usable (can `get()` but cannot `add()`).

Comment: This post seems to explain it pretty well... http://stackoverflow.com/a/12973616/828193

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Also make sure both list and arraylist are from the same package... I.e make sure they are both from java.util, otherwise you get an error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One sentence, because

> Generic types are not polymorphic

i.e., even though `java.lang.String` is a subtype of `java.lang.Object` polymorphism doesn't apply to generic types. It only applies to collection types. thus

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //this isn't valid
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(); //valid
List<? extends Object> list = new ArrayList<String>();//valid
```

**[Why can't generic types be polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993745/add-strings-through-use-of-generic-extends-causes-compiler-error/13993770#13993770)**

Answer (score 2):

`A` is a super type of `B` does not imply `List<A>` is a super type of `List<B>`. If such proposition holds, consistency of type system will be violated. Consider the following case:

```
// ! This code cannot pass compilation.
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> list2 = list1;  // Error
// Previous conversion causes type contradiction in following statements.
list2.add(new SomeOtherClass());
String v = list1.get(0);  // list1.get(0) is not String!
```

That's why `List<Object>` should not be super type of `List<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you define what possible list can be associated with.

The correct way would be

`List<?> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

which is the same as

`List<? extends Object> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String>()
```

with

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()
```

or

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>()
```

It is important here that you operate with the same data type

Or you can also use

```
 List<?> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Comment: Declaring the 2nd way with `<?>` will make all methods which takes the type T from the generic unusable, only methods which doesn't involve T can be invoked.

Comment: what is use of List<?> list = new ArrayList<Object>();  here we cannot element?

Answer (score 0):

The type of the variable declaration **must** match the type you pass to the actual object type. If you declare
`List<Foo>` foo then whatever you assign to the foo reference **MUST** be of the
generic type . Not a subtype of `<Foo>`. Not a `supertype` of `<Foo>`.

```
Simple Generic types are not polymorphic
```

`List<Parent> myList = new ArrayList<Child>() \\ Invalid`