# Why java gives compilation error while assigning List<String> to List<Object>

Tags: java, generics

Why the last line does not work where as `objectList.add("test");` works fine.

```
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

    objectList.add("test");
    stringList.add("test");
    objectList = stringList; //Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to List<Object>
```

Comment: In order to stop the next line being `objectList.add(new Object());`. If your assignment worked, `stringList` would then contain something that is not a String.

Comment: You can add only Strings to `List<String>` whereas you can add any object to `List<Object>`. This post has a good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972910/why-and-what-of-polymorphic-generic-types/12973616#12973616